# Django forms, POST

Tags: django, django-forms, http-post

Django beginner.
 I need to get user's choices and show the information to the user based on the data entered by the user.
 For this I am using a form to fetch the data from url1 and I am posting the data to another url, url2 whose view function will process the data and show the information. All working fine.
I don't want to save the form's data into the database, that's why I am not redirecting after validating the form in url1 views' post method.
POST data can't go with redirects.
If I validate as well as process the form in url1 then I need to display the information in url1 itself, I need the urlname changed to url2 when displaying the information.
Is there any standard way to do this thing?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post some of your existing code for this problem. That might make it easier for someone to suggest things. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the session for that. Save the data to the session on submit in view1, then redirect to view2 and get the data from the session for display.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot. But the browser should accept cookies.